# How do I fix "Unexpected unindent" error with try/except/else syntax

Tags: python, compiler-errors, indentation, except, try-except

**anything after the else in the while not statement has indentation problems** and i'm sure its because i'm formatting incorrectly. What is the correct way to write this?

I've tried moving around statements but could not figure it out

valid_data = False

```
while not valid_data:


    try:
        qty = int(input("How many would you like? (1-10)> "))
    except Exception as detail:
        print("Error: ", detail)
    else:
        try:
            if qty >= 1 and qty <= 10:
                valid_data = True
    finally:
        print("valid entry")
```

Actual results are for qty to be set to user input between 1 and 10 without possible invalid entry, such as if a user inputs a string the code wont crash. For this assignment I HAVE to use try/except syntax.

Comment: Your nested try lacks an except or finally.

Comment: The second `try` has no `except`. I'm not sure why you have `try` there, since there can't be an error when comparing integers.

Comment: basically you have mixed tabs with spaces.  Copy to an editor and change all tabs to 4 spaces

Answer (score 0):

You messed up with indentation: your `finally` statement and the `print` below it are 
 missing additional 4 spaces of indentation. If you want, you can copy & paste the fixed version:

```
while not valid_data:
    try:
        qty = int(input("How many would you like? (1-10)> "))
    except Exception as detail:
        print("Error: ", detail)
    else:
        try:
            if qty >= 1 and qty <= 10:
                valid_data = True
        finally:
            print("valid entry")
```